# loop though jpgs one by one to download to computer

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, web-scraping

Im trying to teach myself some python and Ive been watching  youtube videos :)

One task I had was to grab a picture and download it to my working folder. I solved it but wanted to take it one step further. I created a list of jps and wanted to iterate though them one by one and download them. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
base = 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/'
test = [ linkz.find('img').get('src') for linkz in find_all].

urls = [urljoin(base, t) for t in test]
gets me this list  - ['https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/lake_como.jpg',
 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/pontevecchio.jpg',
 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/riomaggiore.jpg']
```

right now im sending this as a single item like this -

```
sending = [urllib.request.urlretrieve( split , l) for split in urls][0]
```

l comes from this below:

```
myList =  [i.split('italy/', 1)[-1] for i in urls]
for l in myList:
    print(l)

lake_como.jpg
pontevecchio.jpg
riomaggiore.jpg
```

I want to be able to send each link through one by one and download all the pics.  Also for some reason when I run for l in myList: print (l) if I print l on another line only "riomaggiore.jpg" is showing up and not the other 2 jpgs??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `requests` library to do this:

```
import requests

urls = ['https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/lake_como.jpg',
 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/pontevecchio.jpg',
 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/riomaggiore.jpg']

for img_num,url in enumerate(urls):
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open(f'D:\\Img_{img_num+1}.jpg','wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

Output Images:

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Image 3:

[image]

You can also achieve the same result using `urllib.request.urlretrieve`:

```
import urllib.request as req

urls = ['https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/lake_como.jpg',
 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/pontevecchio.jpg',
 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/images/italy/riomaggiore.jpg']

[req.urlretrieve(url,f'D:\\Img_{img_num+1}.jpg') for img_num,url in enumerate(urls)]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great! Also, I had to consistently use double back slashes throughout my file path.